# Where do the quest rewards items go if my inventory is full?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Where do the quest rewards items go if my inventory is full? Does someone know where I can find them? I'm playing the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: Happened to me also. Questgiver dropped the sack, I went into Craft Hall to sell items, and sack was gone on return. On a similar note, while in the Craft Hall I leveled, and learned the ability to summon the minion. One leaving the Hall he disappeared, well before his time should have run out. Seems to me that certain items "dematerialize" when you zone in or out of an area, rather than being on a set timer. Guess we need to sell or destroy excess before turning in quests.

Answer (score 5):

Rewards that don't fit in your inventory get dropped into a loot sack at the feet of the quest giver. I don't know how long the sack lasts, but it should be well long enough for you to run to a shop and sell your junk and get back.

Comment: On the PS3 I had this happen. Left the hut where the bag was dropped, zoned back into town, zoned into the merchants area, sold, and then reversed to find out the bag was gone. Didn't last as long as I expected. :(

Comment: @qor72 Ah. I guess then it is time to make the hard decision to destroy an item or two to get your rewards.

Comment: I've had a few "reward items" disappear when my inventory was full when I talked to the quest giver - for instance, at the end of the "kill the mountain trolls" quest you're supposed to get a sword, and it just disappeared.  Essential quest items tend to appear in these types of sacks, though.